# How do I make the Drupal-Core Forum display only to members, and ask for login details otherwise

Tags: drupal-6, forum

I'm trying to create a website, that has a menu based on Primary Links on the top of the site.  The one menu item is for a 'Members Forum'.

I want this menu item visible to all users (Anonymous/Authorized), but if an Anonymous user clicks on the item, instead of displaying "Access Denied", I'd prefer to show a custom message "such as please login to access the forum".  If an Authorized user clicks it, obviously I want them to go straight to the page.

In the Forum module, I've set up a container for the forum that is only viewable for Authorized users, so that when an Anonymous user clicks the menu item, they get the Access Denied error.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the 'Redirect 403 to User Login' which solved my problem perfectly.